# How to refresh Riverpod FutureProvider using FlutterHooks useEffect

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, riverpod, flutter-hooks

I am developing mobile application with flutter using flutter hooks.
I want to refresh Riverpod FuttureProvider using useEffect,
but it doesn't work nicely...

My code is

```
@hwidget
Widget someWidget(BuildContext context) {
  final futureProvider = useProvider(myFutureProvider);

  useEffect(() {
    context.refresh(futureProvider);
  }, [someKeys]);

  return searchFetch.when(
      data: (data) => TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
              context.refresh(futureProvider);
          },
          child: Text('refresh')
      ),
      loading: () => Text('Loading...'),
      error: (error, stack) => Text('Error.'));
}
```

When tap TextButton, refresh works fine.(I can see 'Loading...' text.)
However, refresh written by useEffect only updates the data and 'Loading...' text cannot be seen.

How should I rewrite it.

Comment: You are not refreshing the same providers, in the button you refresh `searchFetchProvider`, and in the useEffect `futureProvider`

Comment: I think on `futureProvider` you need refresh by  `context.read(myFutureProvider).initData()`  and it should reflect the UI, and i prefer using `Consumer` .

Comment: @croxx5f
Sorry, that was a typo when abstracting my code.
In my production code, they are the same Provider.
The code I wrote for the question has been fixed.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh
It looks like there is no initData() in context.read(FutureProvider)

Comment: You should update both hooks and riverpod packages to the latest version. You can no longer do context.read and useProvider has been deprecated.